# Как ежесекундно обновлять значение без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, функции, setinterval

Нужно, чтобы каждую секунду обновлялось значение метки Unix без перезагрузки страницы. Так не работает:

```
function time() 
{ 
  return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000); 
} 
document.write(time()); 
setInterval(time, 1000);
```

Comment: оно то как раз обновляется, вы просто не видите. Если внутри функции time() вставить console.log("Обновление"), то в консоле Вы увидите эту надпись каждую секунду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша функция time() ведь просто возвращает значение, чего вы ожидали?

```
    var currentTime; 
    function time(){
        return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000); 
    };

    setInterval(function(){
        currentTime = time()
    }, 1000);

    //В переменной currentTime будет постоянно актуальное значение
```

Вопрос в другом, зачем вам ежесекундно обновлять переменную, если можно в нужном месте в нужный момент просто обратится к time(): var $mySituativeTime = time()